# apposition clause and use of that

Tags: that, appositives

In the sentence below:

"The other theory underlying Wright's design is that of organic architecture: that structure should appear to be an extension of their surroundings. "

Question: I know the first that is referring to "theory," but what I am confused is that why colon is used here? Because I think the second "that" is leading an apposition clause explaining what the preceding " the theory of organic architecture" is.

Comment: You mean "an apposition clause", not "a".

Comment: Yes, you could include a 'namely' before the second 'that'. Colons are rather old-fashioned, but can be used to introduce appositives (and most other things). It's an attempt to get rid of a few words, while not introducing ambiguity or garden-pathiness.